# Cannot send data through as epoll-client

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, epoll

I've created a socket, set it into nonblock state, got an addr by getaddrinfo, connected and then added it to the EPOLL with EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT flags.
On my next iteration of epoll_wait it got instantly triggered as EPOLLOUT but when i try to write\send data i get an EINPROGRESS(115) error.
Any idea would be useful. Thanks

EDIT 0:
I'm using LT epoll

EDIT 1:
Question is invalid. I thought that when connection is finished it will trigger EPOLLIN as listener-socket do but it triggers EPOLLOUT.
Thanks for you answers

Comment: Did `connect` completed?

Comment: Are you saying that `write` or `send` returned -1 and an immediate check of `errno` returned `EINPROGRESS`? Can you show us the code from the call to `write` or `send` all the way to the code that detected the `EINPROGRESS` condition? Are you sure `errno` wasn't just still `EINPROGRESS` from a previous call to `connect` and you checked `errno` when there was no error?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting EINPROGRESS (which is not an error) because the socket is set to non-blocking ... so it's not blocking, at all. Are you sure you want to set it "into nonblock state"?

The point of using something like epoll is to avoid the whole blocking issue by being told when it's safe to use the socket.